# permission denied in COPY, logical replication for postgres on ec2 to postgres rds

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a postgres (11.7) instance on EC2 that I'm replicating to Postgres 11 on RDS. I started this yesterday but am noticing that no records seem to show up. I looked through the tables but none seem to have any data in them after 14hrs of replication.

I started replication like this:

On source:

```
CREATE ROLE replrds;
ALTER ROLE replrds WITH NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEDB LOGIN REPLICATION NOBYPASSRLS CONNECT PASSWORD 'xxxxx';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db_name to replrds;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO replrds;
CREATE PUBLICATION rds_pub FOR ALL TABLES;
```

On target: `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION rds_subscription CONNECTION 'host=10.x.x.x port=5432 password=pw user=us dbname=db_name' PUBLICATION rds_pub;`

On the master I see this in the logs:

```
2020-03-22 17:21:20.264 UTC,"replrds","db_name",4539,"10.x.x.x:40648",5e779e90.11bb,4,"COPY",2020-03-22 17:21:20 UTC,3/2292853,0,ERROR,42501,"permission denied for schema public",,,,,,"COPY public.tablea TO STDOUT",,,"rds_subscription_40974_sync_30288"
```

I feel like I've set up the permission correctly but not sure why I keep seeing this...

---------------EDIT--------------

So I got this to work by assigning `superuser` to the `replrds` user on the source, but I'm guessing this is way to permissive and not the right answer...I can't seem to figure out what permissions to grant this user...

Comment: If this works, it must be an Amazon extension.  In community PostgreSQL, CONNECT is a privilege, not an attribute.  It cannot be specified on ALTER ROLE.

Comment: When you issued your grants, were you connected to db_name, or were you still connected to whatever database you used to create db_name?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message here is pretty diagnostic:

> permission denied for schema public

By default your user should already have those permissions.  Either you went out of your way to revoke them, or Aurora has departed from community PostgreSQL  (If the later, the made it pretty hard to find it in the docs).  In db_name, you could do:

```
GRANT USAGE on schema public to replrds;
```